# Understanding this queue and stack code

Tags: java, stack, queue, reverse

The following code involves a queue and stack.  What does it do and how?

```
public static void theCode (Queue q)
{
   ListStack s = new ListStack();

   while(! q.isEmpty())
       s.push(q.dequeue());

   while(! s.isEmpty())
       q.enqueue(s.pop());
```

Comment: Would you like to complete the question?

Comment: It reverses the queue.

Comment: What specifically do you not understand about it?

Comment: this is whole thing,

Comment: i don't fully understand how this method works

Comment: Sounds like you're not good in English. Ask a friend to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your mouse over the queue and stack tags and read the popup blurbs.  One adds and deletes items from the same end of a stack, but (normally) opposite ends of a queue.  Here is an example of the steps for a 3 elememt queue, with one item moved at a time.

```
Q: [1,2,3];  S: []
Q: [2,3];  S: [1]
Q: [3];  S: [1,2]
Q: [];  S: [1,2,3]
Q: [3];  S: [1,2]
Q: [3,2];  S: [1]
Q: [3,2,1];  S: []
```

The queue is reversed.  This process would operate the same in any language with queue and stack classes.

Comment: Hi Terry! Follow my [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85335/tkinter?referrer=e2qMh-8Ye8-dLhj70wmHBA2) on Area 51 in order to create a website completely dedicated to `tkinter/ttk`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find this ListStack class in the API. However, this method looks like it is trying to loop through the given Queue (which is *q* as specified in the parameters) and copy the contents into ListStack *s*.